# How to mimic mouse movement and event

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I have absolutely no clue how javascript works and I'm trying to add code to my script that will mimic mouse movement. What I'm trying to do is purchase shoes from Nike using a bot. All my bot does is add my size to the cart upon clicking the link from twitter but I understand that it'll be detected as a bot if I don't have a mouse event. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
var size = "12";
var amount = 1;

function addToCart() {
    var sizesList=document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0];
    function setQuantity() {
        document.getElementsByName("qty")[0].selectedIndex = amount-1;
    }
    function setSizeValue() {
        for (var i=0; i<sizesList.length; i++){
            if(sizesList.options[i].text == size) {
                document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0].selectedIndex = i;
                setQuantity();
            }
        }
    }
    if(sizesList != undefined) {
        setSizeValue();
        document.getElementsByClassName("add-to-cart nsg-button--nike-orange")    [0].click();
    } else {
        setTimeout("addToCart()", 250);
    }
}
setTimeout("addToCart()", 250);
```

Comment: "*I have absolutely no clue how java works*"--first off, Java != JavaScript.

Comment: wtf i'm so curious as to why you actually need this

Comment: @HC_ because nowadays sneakers have high resell value and everyone is fighting for sneakers so u gotta check out the cart very fast because a lot of people are buying it on nike.com .

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very hackish. Why would you ever need a bot to buy shoes from Nike? Also, Java !=Javascript. You're using Javascript to do this.

For simulating mouse events, check out [Event constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)

Comment: because nowadays sneakers have high resell value and everyone is fighting for sneakers so u gotta check out the cart very fast because a lot of people are buying it on nike.com